# How to capture mouse click on Gtk.Stack

Tags: gtk, vala

I would like to load the contents of a tab only when the user clicks on the same. Is there some property of the Stack or the Widget which I can use for this. I'm coding in Vala and I have currently worked around this by loading the content on the build of the UI. A sample piece of code will help a lot.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't quite understand. What would you like to do, and why?

Comment: Basically, I am developing a Network Utility application (Nutty) in GTK+3. Each tab of the application has various tabs for different functions - Basic Network Card info, Traceroute to a site/IP, Open Ports, Devices Discovery on Network. While each tab has user initiated infrmation, the  ports info tab one should be opened with information without any user interaction. Currently i'm populating the info in the tab at UI build time which makes the application open with a little bit of lag which can be avoided if the info is populated at run time on click of tab.

Comment: Nutty on Launchpad, just in case someone wants to take a look at the source code or screen shots: https://launchpad.net/nutty

Comment: Ah. In that case, you should probably connect to the stack's `"notify::visible-child"` or `"notify::visible-child-name"` signal (see [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#GObject-notify) for a description of what the `"notify"` signal is) and only load/update your data when the required page is switched to. You could probably even use a GtkOverlay or something of the sort to show a GtkSpinner while you load your data.

Comment: @andlabs : Thanks for your suggestion. I was able to capture the click of the tab with the Stack's notify signal. Here is the vala code snippet just in case someone will benefit from it:

Comment: stack.add_titled(ports_layout_box, "my-tab", "FOO");stack.notify["visible-child-name"].connect ((sender, property) => {
   if("my-tab"==stack.get_visible_child_name()){//TO DO } });

Comment: @SiddharthaDas I took the liberty to make this an answer. In the future you should add an answer on your own, you can also edit your own question in case you only want to update your progress on finding a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from OPs comment:

```cs
stack.add_titled (ports_layout_box, "my-tab", "FOO");
stack.notify["visible-child-name"].connect ((sender, property) => { 
        if ("my-tab" == stack.get_visible_child_name ()) { 
            // TO DO
        } 
    });
```